# Remove Chapter Number from Header--Memoir Class

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I'm working in the `memoir` class using A6. For this format, I want to remove both the word "Chapter" from the default `memoir` page heading style as well as the chapter number, so that only the chapter title is included in the header. Removing the word "chapter" can be achieved by adding the following after `\begin{Document}`:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
```

But the chapter number remains in the page header. I added this command:

```
\renewcommand\printchapternonum{}
```

but it had no effect.

What is a quick and easy way to remove the chapter number from the header? I looked at the `fancyhdr` package and there is conflict with `memoir`; similarly, I tried changing to `scrbook` but there were errors (baseline skip already defined).

There has to be a simple way of doing this.

[Later]

Thank you everyone for your helpful answers.

Answer (score 5):

The proper `memoir` way of doing this

```
\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}
}
\pagestyle{headings} % activate changes
```

there is no need to try to figure out how the internals work or that sort of thing.

You might want to read http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-2/madsen/

Comment: It would be nice if the `\addtopsmarks` features were explained also in the manual (they aren't, except for a single example which explains almost nothing).

Comment: Its on page 116. What else is needed? (I agree that the manual is too cluttered with examples and code presentation mixed together.)

Comment: BTW, @egreg were you referring to the link I provided? That is just an article about page styles in `memoir` it is not meant as a manual.

Comment: The `\addtopsmarks` feature is really difficult to find in the manual and I find its description too scanty. That said, I upvoted your answer, since it says much more than “look at the manual”. I surely wouldn't have been able to guess at `nonumber`.

Comment: `nonumber` is an `\createmark` 'option' and is explained on page 113 in the `memoir` manual. Someday I hope to get the time to rewrite the memoir manual, but that is not going to happen anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine `\chaptermark`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

An image of the header on page two:

[image]

Uppercased text is not really pleasing, so perhaps you could use small caps instead:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
  \markboth{\textsc{#1}}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With a `twoside` style, the `\chaptermark` command is defined as

```
> \chaptermark=macro:
#1->\@setclcnt {chapter}{@memmarkcntra}\advance \c@@memmarkcntra \m@ne \markboth 
{\memUChead {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth > \c@@memmarkcntra \if@mainmatter \@nameuse 
{chaptermarksn}{\@chapapp \ \@nameuse {thechapter}. \ }\fi \fi #1}}{}.
```

It's not easy to find the definition in `memoir.cls`, because it's modified during processing the class code, so I used `\show\chaptermark`.

The solution is then easy by looking at the definition of `\chaptermarksn` which just uses its argument:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermarksn}[1]{}
```

because the chapter tag and number are passed as arguments to it.

Example

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand\chaptermarksn[1]{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]